# SSL not working with IBM MQ 8 client jars

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq, mq

SSL works with IBM MQ 6 client jars but the same code doesn't work with IBM 8 jars.Did anyone faced issue with IBM 8 client jars.

Code:

```
            com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager qmRequest = null;
            com.ibm.mq.MQQueue qRequest = null;

            com.ibm.mq.MQMessage reqMsg = new com.ibm.mq.MQMessage();
            reqMsg.writeString(new String("first MQ SSL Message test"));
            reqMsg.messageId = "1".getBytes();
            reqMsg.correlationId = "2".getBytes(); 



            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:/keystore/testKS.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "12345678");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:/keystore/testKS.jks"); 
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "12345678"); 
            Hashtable<String,Object> propMap = new Hashtable<String,Object>();

            propMap.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost");
            propMap.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY,  1415);
            propMap.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "testG");
            propMap.put(MQConstants.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY, "CN=ibmwebspheremqtestqu");

            String qmNameRequest = "testQu";
            String qNameRequest = "testQQ";
            propMap.put(MQConstants.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY,  "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA");
            qmRequest = new com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager(qmNameRequest,propMap);

            int reqQueueOpt = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT;
            qRequest = qmRequest.accessQueue(qNameRequest, reqQueueOpt);
            reqMsg.messageType = MQConstants.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
            com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions reqMsgOpt = new com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions();
            reqMsgOpt.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT;

            qRequest.put(reqMsg, reqMsgOpt);
            qRequest.close();
            qmRequest.disconnect();
```

The above code works with IBM jdks but with oracle jdk it always fails and throws exception related to SSL.

Comment: The exception is important, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840

Did you set the JVM environment variable "-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false" as noted in the IBM support doc?

Comment: yeah I tried setting this and 1 way SSL worked but why does the same code works for mq 6 client jars , is it kind of regression?